# is there anyway to extend ApplicationUser to foreign key to ApplicationRole to get all data in EF core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole 
{
    public ApplicationRole()
    {
        ApplicationUser = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
{

    public string RoleId { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; } = new ApplicationRole();
}
```

I extend a RoleId in AspNetUsers because of I want only one role in one user,
So I make a forigen key in mssql (AspNetUsers.RoleId FK AspNetUserRoles.Id)

but when I use `_userManager.Users` this method, it only be a ApplicationRole new model

How can i get AspNetUserRoles Table data to ApplicationUser model when I use `_userManager.Users` ?

Comment: I solved, because of the lazy load, so i use _userManager.Users.Include(x => x.Role) can get role

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should set a unique constraint for UserRole if you want only one Role for a User, and that you should use provided navigations.
Here is my example:

```cs
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

[Index(nameof(UserId), IsUnique = true)]    // unique constraint
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RoleId))]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role : IdentityRole
{
    public IEnumerable<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And in DbContext (which extends `IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>, UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>`):

```cs
builder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.UserRoles).WithOne(ur => ur.User)
    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId).HasPrincipalKey(u => u.Id);
builder.Entity<Role>()
    .HasMany(r => r.UserRoles).WithOne(ur => ur.Role)
    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId).HasPrincipalKey(r => r.Id);
builder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithMany(r => r.Users)
    .UsingEntity<UserRole>();
builder.Entity<Role>()
    .HasMany(r => r.Users).WithMany(u => u.Roles)
    .UsingEntity<UserRole>();
```